# html 5 audio tag in iOS/iphone 6 no longer working in a password-protected directory

Tags: html, ios, iphone, html5-audio, basic-authentication

I have a simple html 5 audio tag (below) on a page in a password protected directory.
The directory is protected by HTTP Basic authentication.

It was working fine on iOS7, on Safari. Now when I click on the Play button, nothing happens.
On other directories that are not password protected, it still works fine.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="audio/01-10r.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src="audio/01-10r.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="audio/01-10r.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, just a hunch here but if its working for you in other directories I would say check your source from which your loading the file. If it's working in one directory and not the other I'd say its not loading the file correctly using the "src" source you have set. But if you want to post more details about your structure I don't mind looking over it further.

According to W3 here's the browsers it supports
[image: W3 Browser Support]